# Fractal plane continuum with order $\aleph_0$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, plane-geometry

*Continuum* means compact and connected.

Define the order  of a point $x$ in a continuum $X$ to be the least cardinal $\alpha$ such that $X$ has a neighborhood base of open sets at $x$ with no more than $\alpha$ points their boundaries.

[image]

The Sierpinski triangle has three points of order $2$, countably many points of order $4$ (the vertices of the other triangles), and all other points are of order $3$.

The Sierpinski carpet has order $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$ at each of its points.

I am looking for something to go between the Sierpinski triangle and the Sierpinski carpet.

**Question 1.** Is there a fractal plane continuum which has order $\aleph_0$ at each of its points?

*Fractal* can be loosely interpreted here to mean "self-similar",  "simple recursive construction", or "intersection of an easily definable nested sequence of plane domains".

A slight variation on Question 1:

**Question 2.** Is there a fractal plane continuum which has a basis of open sets with countably infinite boundaries?

Comment: When your title said "order $\omega$" I was expecting some sort of ordinal invariant.  If you had said "order $\aleph_0$" I would have expected a cardinal, as you indeed explain.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for pointing that out.  There is also something known as "rim-type" of a continuum which is expressed in ordinals.  My property depends on cardinality only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an upper semi-continuous decomposition of the Cantor set times the unit interval which should fit the bill for Question 1, but not for Question 2. It lies in the plane and has a simple recursive construction. Here are the first few steps:

[image]

Comment: There is a problem at the top and bottom "endpoints" which can be easily resolved.  As it stands, these points only have order 1. But the order becomes $\aleph_0$ everywhere if we squeeze the top and bottom Cantor sets to a single point.